# How distributed app is verified as valid in user's iPhone

Tags: iphone, installation, code-signing, verify

An app can be installed in a device if it is code signed. While installing the code-signed app in a device the app id, certificate and device id is matched against the corresponding details  embedded in the provisioning profile installed in the device. If it is matched then app is installed successfully.

My question is that:
During distribution we will not know and we will not mention the user's device id in distribution profile. Then, how verification is done during installation of distributed app?

Answer (score 0):

When any application is under development stage, we need to add device ID in development profile. In case of distribution, there is nothing like adding device. Anyone having iOS device, can download your application from App Store. there is nothing like verification in i. You just need to enter deployment target for your application. So, if you have kept it 5.0, then anyone having iOS 5.0 and later, can install your application.

Let me know if still you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Correct me if I am wrong: "Since the apps are distributed through Store user feels safer to download it. In case of distribution security is handled based on trust."